# Can yadcf be used to filter rows on a class

Tags: class, datatables, yadcf

Im looking for an easy way to filter 3 cols which certain rows have a specific class. 
I have a datatable for live football games, this shows me inplay stats and if stats get above a certain level I add a class to the TD, for example

```
        if(Number(chars[0])+Number(chars[1])>15)
         {
            $(row).find('td:eq(8)').css('background-color', 'lime');
            $(row).find('td:eq(8)').addClass('lime');
        }
```

On a busy day I can have over 100 live games at a time and I would like to filter just showing the games which have a class of 'lime'. There are 3 cols I shade using this so ideally I want a single filter to cover all 3

Ive tried using the search plugin for datatables but I can only get it to work on the first page of results.

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   responsive: {
        details: {

        }
    },
        "ajax": "console.json",
          "search": {
            "regex": true
          },
        "columns": [
            {
                "class":          'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "time" },
            { "data": "firstgoal" },
            { "data": "score" },
            { "data": "league" },
            { "data": "teams", "defaultContent": "0" },
            { "data": function (data, type, dataToSet) {
                return data.nextover + "% (" + data.sno + ")";}
            },
            { "data": "pi1",
               "render": function (data, type, row)  {
               return  '<span class="show-modalp1" data-modal-id="'+ row.gameid + '">' + data + '</span>';       
             }},                   
            { "data": "pi2",
              "render": function (data, type, row) {
              return '<span class="show-modalp2" data-modal-id="'+ row.gameid + '">' + data + '</span>';

             }},
            { "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                            return '<img src="'+JsonResultRow.rc+'" class="center">';
                        }}

        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        rowCallback: function(row, data, index){
             if((data["nextover"] >85 && data["sno"]>14) ||  (data["nextover"] >70 && data["sno"]>10 && data["time"]>=70) ||  (data["nextover"] >55 && data["sno"]>5 && data["time"]>=81))  
             {
                $(row).find('td:eq(6)').css('background-color', 'lime');
                $(row).find('td:eq(7)').addClass('lime');
            }
            else
            {
                $(row).find('td:eq(6)').css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
            }
            var chars = data["pi2"].split(':');
            if(Number(chars[0])+Number(chars[1])>15)
             {
                $(row).find('td:eq(8)').css('background-color', 'lime');
                $(row).find('td:eq(8)').addClass('lime');
            }
            else
            {
                $(row).find('td:eq(8)').css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
            }
            var chars2 = data["pi1"].split(':');
            if(Number(chars2[0])+Number(chars2[1])>70)
             {
                $(row).find('td:eq(7)').css('background-color', 'lime');
                $(row).find('td:eq(7)').addClass('lime');
            }
            else
            {
                $(row).find('td:eq(7)').css('background-color', 'mistyrose');
            }
        },
        drawCallback: function(settings) {
        $(".show-modalp1").each(function() { 
          var id = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
            $(this).popover({
            content: function() {
                return '<div style="width: 440px; height=220px"><iframe src="../pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=' + id + '&pi=pi1" width=440 height=220></iframe></div>';
            },
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'left',
            html: true,
            title: 'Pressure Index 1 = (10*SOT)+(10*SOFT)+1 per 5%poss'
          }
        )
        });
        $(".show-modalp2").each(function() { 
          var id = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
            $(this).popover({
            content: function() {
                return '<div style="width: 440px; height=220px"><iframe src="../pressure/showgraph.php?gameid=' + id + '&pi=pi2" width=440 height=220></iframe></div>';
            },
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'left',
            html: true,
            title: 'Pressure Index 2 = 1 *dangerous attack - 1 point if no corners in last 8'
          }
        )
        });

      },




    } );



$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(function(_,__,rowIdx){
  return $(table.row(rowIdx).node()).has('td.lime').length || !$('#showLime').hasClass('limeOnly');
});










    $('#example').on('draw.dt', function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                }); 


    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );



    $('#reset').on('click', function () {
          table.columns(1).search("").draw();
        table.ajax.reload(null, false);


})


$('#secondhalf').on('click', function () {
            regExSearch = '(4[6-9]|[5-8][0-9]|90)';
            table.column(1).search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
}); 

$('#firsthalf').on('click', function () {
     regExSearch = '([1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])';
     table.column(1).search(regExSearch, true, false).draw();
});

$('#halftime').on('click', function () {
      table.columns(1).search("HT").draw();
});
;


$('#showLime').on('change', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('limeOnly');
   table.draw();
});


    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 30000 )




}
);
```

Comment: Your above code can be way more compact. At the very least, you don't need to assign both background color and class. The latter is enough if you link corresponding class with background color property inside CSS file. Your render function can be reused with column index as a parameter. What you do with row callback option can be achieved with `columnDefs.createdCell` option in much more concise manner. The same is applicable to the `drawCallback`. Your RegExp filtering looks like can be done without RegExp, which may be even faster as the number of records grows big enough.

Comment: Hi @Yevgen Gorbunkov , thanks for the advice, Im new to databtables and JS, and all of what you have put above makes perfect sense and I will implement. May I ask how I can filter without regex though

Comment: Let's get your filtering issue solved first. Then you may ask another question about things you'd like to optimize and I'd gladly look into that. There's not enough room for fixing that in the comments.